# LDAP query for Barracuda

Tags: firewall, exchange-2007, spam, barracuda

I have a barracuda spam firewall 300 that I just got installed the other day.  I'm working on an LDAP query for using it with my exchange server.  What i have so far is:

```
(&
(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)
(|
    (sAMAccountName=${recipient_local_part})
    (othermailbox=smtp:${recipient_local_part}@ourdomain.com)
    (proxyaddresses=smtp:${recipient_local_part}@ourdomain.com)
    (mail=${recipient_email})
    (userPrincipalName=${recipient_local_part})
)
)
```

I've formatted it for your convenience.
What I'm trying to do is filter out users who are disabled in the directory, since they may have valid addresses, but I don't want to accept mail for them anymore.  We keep their email addresses for a long time, but company policy prevents me from deleting them from the directory.

When the query runs, i get the following error:

```
failed to issue LDAP find operation: Bad search filter
```

The query works without the (!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2), but that is the line that filters out disabled accounts.

How do I use LDAP to effectively filter out disabled accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard for me to test this one, but I think you need the parens to group the !useraccountcontrol and the or block.

```
(&
 (
  (!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)
  (|
        (sAMAccountName=${recipient_local_part})
        (othermailbox=smtp:${recipient_local_part}@ourdomain.com)
        (proxyaddresses=smtp:${recipient_local_part}@ourdomain.com)
        (mail=${recipient_email})
        (userPrincipalName=${recipient_local_part})
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: That did it.  The parenthesis I had weren't enough apparently... LDAP is so picky.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you checking so many options? The proxyAddresses part should be more than enough:

(& 
(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)
(proxyaddresses=smtp:${recipient_local_part}@ourdomain.com)
)

Thanks,

Brian Desmond

Active Directory MVP